# Why is webcam freezing after certain time

Tags: c#, wpf, aforge

I coded an application that has a webcam which can SCAN QR codes:

```
VideoCaptureDevice LocalWebCam;
public FilterInfoCollection LoaclWebCamsCollection;

void Cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    try
    {
        BitmapImage bi;
        using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone())
        {
            bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bi.EndInit();
        }
        bi.Freeze();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { frameHolder.Source = bi; }));
    }
    catch
    {
        //some error
    }
```

and

```
void Window2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoaclWebCamsCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
    LocalWebCam = new VideoCaptureDevice(LoaclWebCamsCollection[0].MonikerString);
    LocalWebCam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Cam_NewFrame);
    LocalWebCam.Start();
    timer.Start(); // QR CODE SCANNER
}
```

It works all fine **but** when I let the application run for some longer time the webam freezes. Does someone have an idea why?

Comment: Personally, I would get rid of this exception-eating empty `catch` clause and inspect the actual error.

Comment: I'd say `bi.Freeze();` might be for something here

Comment: @Rafalon No, `Freeze()` just supports the [freezable pattern](https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/Freezable-Pattern).

Comment: Check in Windows Task Manager whether your application is eating up too many resources (on task manager page 'Details', check columns for memory, GDI objects, handles, ...)

Comment: @FrankM yeah but we do not know what happens to `frameHolder.Source` aka `bi`. If anything tries to modify it there, then an exception will be thrown, right?

Comment: What is `frameHolder`? If you freeze a `BitmapImage`, you don't need to torture the `Dispatcher` anymore, because the `BitmapImage` can be accessed by different threads.

Comment: How often `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` will be called? If more often wenn 20 ms it could be a problem.

Comment: @dymanoid frameHolder is an Image Control.